# Fail to extract the RDF from neo4j Browser

Tags: neo4j, rdf, neo4j-browser

I am trying to extract the rdf file from my graph, using commands like :GET /rdf/neo4j/describe/12，but it failed and shows "

```
Could not fetch URL: "undefined". This could be due to the remote server policy. See your web browsers error console for more information."
```

I can successfully run http://localhost:7474/rdf/neo4j/describe/12 on my own webbrowser after log in as a admin account.And it returns an "empty" rdf file that only has a prefix.
I am also log in the neo4j browser with the same account,
And because I don't know how to extract a path or a portion of the graph on web browser, I really need to know how to run it on the neo4j browser.

Comment: what/how did you install to get the RDF of neo4j database?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run `:get http://localhost:7474/rdf/neo4j/describe/12` in the Neo4j browser (the whole URL instead of just the final bit)?

In order to find out why you're getting an empty dataset as a result I'd need a few more details. Here are some ideas for you to test.

- If it's a graph built by importing RDF, nodeid-based search won't work, you'll have to do it by URI
- If you've not imported RDF but built a native property graph then you won't need a graph config (check there's not one or it will mislead the RDF export endpoint and things won't work)
- Again, if it's a native property graph, obvious but worth checking, make sure a node with id 12 exist?
  `match (n) where id(n) = 12 return n`

Comment: Yes you're right, just miseed the whole URL. I have finished it after that, thanks.